# Is it possible to init a python class with specific argument?

Tags: python

Is the following possible in Python? I was googling out for a while, however wasn't lucky with an answer.

```
class X_Class:
    def __init__(self, arg_0, arg_1 = False, arg_2 = False):
        self.arg_1 = arg_1
        self.arg_2 = arg_2

myX = X_Class("anything", arg_2 = True)
```

If yes, how to refer to argument of **init** function?

EDIT: The core issue was in superclass, however thank you for getting me quickly on the right track.

Comment: Other than forgetting self.arg_0 = arg_0 in your constructor, what is your code not doing, that you want it to?

Answer (score 5):

Yep — that's exactly the syntax, in fact:

```
class X_Class(object):
    def __init__(self, arg_0, arg_1=False, arg_2=False):
        self.arg_0 = arg_0
        self.arg_1 = arg_1
        self.arg_2 = arg_2

myX = X_Class("anything", arg_2=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call any callable, you can specify what argument is what:

```
def f(x, y=1, z=2): pass
f(0, z=3)
```

So your code is a correct implementation of what you describe.